# Android - Issue Passing and saving the data between two activities using intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `TextView` and a `Button` in my first activity and an `EditText` and a `Button` in my second Activity.

In Second Activity i want to pass an `EditText` value to the first Activity and show `TextView` in the first Activity, also i want to save the given  edittext value after returning back from the first activity

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
        TextView textView;
        Button button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    gotoActivityB();
                }
            });

        }

      /*  private void gotoActivityB(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  //0 is a request code
        }*/
      private void gotoActivityB()
      {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
          intent.putExtra("value",textView.getText());
          startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),101);
      }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    // get String data from Intent
                    String returnString = data.getStringExtra("keyName");

                    // set text view with string
                    textView.setText(returnString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Secondactivity

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    EditText edittext;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("value"); // that means you have passed value from activity B to activity A, otherwise activity B is fresh launched.
        if(str!=null)
        {
            edittext.setText(str);
        }
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // get the text from the EditText
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
                String stringToPassBack = editText.getText().toString();

                // put the String to pass back into an Intent and close this activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("keyName", stringToPassBack);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone please help me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In second Activity on button click

use code like this :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("KEY",value);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: the text is being displayed in the activity a  textview  but unable to save in activity b editext after returning from activity a

Comment: private void gotoActivityB() {
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("value",textView.getText());
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),101);
        }
    
    On Second Activity on Create method
    Intent intent = getIntent();
            String str = intent.getStringExtra("value");
    // that means you have passed value from activity B to activity A, otherwise activity B is fresh launched.
    if(str!=null){
    edittext.setText(str);
    also remove onDestroy() from activity B.

Comment: yaa but how can i share can i update my code which is posted already

Comment: have you tried with my solution , if yes then share that code you have implemented

Comment: please change request code to 0;  startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),101); to   startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),0); as  onActivityResult you are checking for if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         // get String data from Intent
         String returnString = data.getStringExtra("keyName");

         // set text view with string
         textView.setText(returnString);
        }
    }

Comment: yaa the text is displayed in the  textview but the data is not saved in the secondactivity edittext

Comment: Okies in your code , you have create new intent again thats why its not showing on edittext.so change this line in Activity A startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class),0); to  startActivityForResult(intent,0); If its done then please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `ActivityA`, change your `gotoActivityB()` method to

```
private void gotoActivityB(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  //0 is a request code
}
```

Then override `onActivityResult` method inside `ActivityA`

```
// This method is called when the second activity finishes
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         // get String data from Intent
         String returnString = data.getStringExtra("keyName");

         // set text view with string
         textView.setText(returnString);
        }
    }
}
```

In your `ActivityB`, write the following code when button is clicked

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

         // get the text from the EditText
         EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
         String stringToPassBack = editText.getText().toString();

         // put the String to pass back into an Intent and close this activity
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.putExtra("keyName", stringToPassBack);
         setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
         finish();
    }
});
```

also remove the `onDestroy()` method from `ActivityB`, it is not needed.

Comment: thank you ,the text is being displayed in the first activity but i want to save the given edit text value after returning back from the first activity

Comment: i am not sure what you want here. Do you want to save the value of EditText in ActivityB when we return to ActivityA from ActivityB?

Comment: Yes Yousaf i want to save the value of EditText in ActivityB when we return from ActivityA to Activity B